# Suggested edit with no diff, absent from revision history

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

What did [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1316739) change? Here is a screenshot from the review queue, with a red circle around all visible changes:

[image: screenshot]

The same user submitted two suggested edits on this post: [the first](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1316718) at 13:05:27 (approved at 13:07:19) and [the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1316739) at 13:11:42 (approved at 13:17:04).

In the post's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3342315/revisions), there is only a link to the second suggestion, but marked with the date of the first suggestion, and the diff is the same one recorded for the first suggestion. (Just before the second suggestion was approved, there was a link to the first suggestion as expected.)

The visible bug is a suggested edit presented for review with no apparent change and no button offering a markdown view. There may be another bug that caused the second suggestion to disappear or be merged with the first one.

(This isn't the first “suggested edit with no diff” bug report, but I can't find another one that looks like the same bug.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Possibly. Note that there was more than 5 minutes between the two suggestions, but less than 5 minutes between the first approval and the second suggestion.

Comment: The [API suggests](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-by-ids#order=desc&sort=creation&ids=536747%3B536740&filter=!9hnGsvP*5&site=stackoverflow&run=true) the change was believed to be in the title, but the action was a noop.

Comment: @TimStone Interesting. Something about the automatically-removed space before the question mark, maybe? The fact that it's a title-only edit explains the lack of a “show markdown” button. The poor presentation of title changes is something I and others have already complained about several times.

Comment: Possibly, yeah. My guess is that the OP tried to make the same edit twice for whatever reason, and that the title edit counted as a change on submit both times, but not on diff. I would have thought any sanitization would be done before checking if something changed though, so I'm not sure how that could happen.

Comment: To further your point about the presentation of title changes, it seems that stripping out trailing space from the title is indeed [not reflected in revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/107542/revisions).

Comment: @TimStone: Looks like it is reflected there now :)